# How to update Rsync over an existing Vagrant (Homestead) configuration?

Tags: vagrant, rsync, homestead

I am using Vagrant+Homestead with RSync.

In **.homestead/Homestead.yaml** I initially left

```
 folders:
     map 
     to 
     type
```

to default values (except changing type to "rsync")

Rsync seems working but even after changing **map** (i.e. source folder) in Homestead.yaml and then running **vagrant provision** and finally **vagrant rsync-auto --poll**, it keeps saying.

```
  Rsycing folder. <folder>,
   Exclude, 
   watching <folder>
```

which is good but *folder* is the original one, **not the one updated** in Homestead.yaml.

**How do I made rsync (Homestead installation) watch a different folder than the "default" one?**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

> vagrant reload

did the trick (had to put an invalid path to be advised by vagrant CLI on this)